# Regular expression to parse robots.txt

Tags: regex

I have the following robots.txt as an example -

```
User-agent: googlebot
User-agent: slurp
User-agent: msnbot
User-agent: teoma
User-agent: W3C-checklink
User-agent: WDG_SiteValidator
Disallow: /
Disallow: /js/
Disallow: /Web_References/
Disallow: /webresource.axd
Disallow: /scriptresource.axd

User-agent: Mediapartners-Google*
Disallow:

User-agent: *
Disallow: /webresource.axd
Disallow: /scriptresource.axd
Disallow: /js/
Disallow: /Web_References/
```

I may be asking too much of regex but I'm wanting to write an expression which will return matches in the following grouped and ordered fashion -

```
Matches
 - [0]
   - [UserAgents]
      - "googlebot"
      - "slurp"
      - "msnbot"
      - "teoma"
      - "W3C-checklink"
      - "WDG_SiteValidator"
    - [Routes]
      - [0]
        - [Permission] "Allow"
        - [Url] "/"
      - [1]
        - [Permission] "Disallow"
        - [Url] "/js/"
      - [2]
        - [Permission] "Disallow"
        - [Url] "/Web_References/"

...

etc

...
```

I've written individual expressions to match elements of the document, however I can't get them to work when pieced together. Maybe someone can point out where I'm going wrong?

**Patterns**

User agents: `(?:user-agent:\s*)(?<UserAgent>[a-z_0-9-*]*)`

Permissions: `(?<Permission>(?:allow|disallow))(?:\s*:\s*)(?<Url>[/0-9_a-z.]*)`

**My attempt**

`((?<UserAgents>(?:user-agent:\s*)(?<UserAgent>[a-z_0-9-*]*))+(?<Routes>(?<Permission>(?:allow|disallow))(?:\s*:\s*)(?<Url>[/0-9_a-z.]*))+)+`

FYI, I'm using Expresso to debug these scripts and have the following checked - Multiline, Compiled and Ignore Case

Comment: What kind of matches *are* you getting?

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to do this with one big regex, rather than just using your separate regexes independently? (Or even using regex at all?) Smashing them all together doesn't make your program better, it just makes things less readable and your code more serpentine.

Comment: @Alex: I don't get any matches.

Comment: I take your point however I think this is a much more concise why of getting the desired result. The only alternative I can think of is to write code to parse each line which must also keep some sort of state, i.e when parsing a 'Route' line, it must know which 'User agents' preceded it so it can act accordingly. I'm open to suggestions please :)

Comment: What language are you working with? Also, storing state isn't a bad thing, nor does it take a lot of code. The regex engine stores tons of state, you just don't see it.

Comment: I'm working in C# 4. Very true - I'll have a go and post my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?:^User-agent: (?<UserAgent>.*?)$)|(?<Permission>^(?:Allow)|(?:Disallow)): (?<Url>.*?)$
```

I'm not sure about that format you want, but the above regex matches and names the parts you are interested in. Maybe you can build on top of that regex. I hardly do C#, but maybe this might work:

```
try {
    Regex regexObj = new Regex("(?:^User-agent: (?<UserAgent>.*?)$)|(?<Permission>^(?:Allow)|(?:Disallow)): (?<Url>.*?)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
    Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
    while (matchResults.Success) {
        for (int i = 1; i < matchResults.Groups.Count; i++) {
            Group groupObj = matchResults.Groups[i];
            if (groupObj.Success) {
                // matched text: groupObj.Value
                // match start: groupObj.Index
                // match length: groupObj.Length
            } 
        }
        matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
    } 
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```